# Check if USB flash drive is USB 3.0 or 3.1 in Windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, usb, usb-flash-drive, usb-3

If I have a USB 3.1 pendrive, how do I check in Windows, if it's actually 3.1, and is not 3.0.

Comment: What does the "safely remove drive" prompt show?

Comment: What connector does it have - Type-A or Type-C?

Comment: So are you asking how to determine if a device is a USB 3.1 Gen 1, which is also known as, USB 3.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

USB 3.1 defines two data rates, SuperSpeed (5 Gbps) and SuperSpeedPlus (10 Gbps). These modes are called as Gen1 and Gen2 speeds. Having a device that is designated as "USB 3.1" doesn't necessarily mean that it supports "Gen2" speed. Also, having a Type-C connector doesn't define any particular speed, it could be even USB 2.0 high-speed.

Up to the date (11/15/2018), general market of USB flash drives doesn't have any interface controllers that operate at Gen2 speed. The situation didn't seem to change since [a year ago](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/327491/117785). The only known devices are [AsMedia  ASM1351/ASm1352/ASM235](http://www.asmedia.com.tw/eng/e_products_list.php?item=83&cate_index=0) USB-SATA bridges that are used in external HDD enclosures and can operate at Gen2 speed. All reports of USB 3.1 Gen2 flash drives appear to be false under deeper investigation, the flash drives operate at Gen1 speeds. Check out [this Reddit discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/buildapc/comments/8z234s/are_there_any_usb_31_gen_2_flash_drives_on_the/) for reference.

Therefore there is a very little chance that your flash drive operates at Gen2 speed.

Comment: Ah! Now I understood. I thought USB 3.1 gen 2 > USB 3.1 gen 1 > USB 3.0. but USB 3.1 gen1 is same speed as USB 3.0